# Live Audio & Video Streaming with orientation change handling in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, audio-streaming, orientation-changes

I am going to implement live audio and video streaming but unable to play audio and video can  any one help me out??

There is also problem with orientation change.when orientation changes it will restart.

Thanks in advance

please any one help

Comment: would you mind to share some code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in you AndroidManifest file;

Add:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

In your activity;

Comment: actually my main task is streaming after that configuration change

Answer (score 0):

`android:configChanges="orientation"` - is considerably "bad practice" since you'll have to deal with all kinds of "configuration changes" (not only screen orientation change) all by yourself, when Android otherwise deal with it for you. In your case I'd create a fragment with all music controls in it and set it to:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

Then add in in the activity startup as:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, MyMusicFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
}
```

Or even from your xml, depend on your case, and if you want to say have different layouts for tablet and phone type of devices.
Fragments are much flexible/modular and will pay back in future when you'll decide to move things arond